# How to determine sql server name

Tags: installation, database, sql-server, sap

I'm trying to install sap business one on my computer. But I can't seem to connect to the database server which is ms sql.

I get the notice: unable to connect to the database server name, and that database is started. Here's what I did:

- Enabled TCP/IP protocol
- Restarted the service

I already tried every single possibility that I could think of:

- COMPUTERNAME/SQLEXPRESS
- localhost

The username and password that I'm using is: sa and b1admin. Which I think is the default as I have seen from the Sql server management studio:

Note: The image isn't updated. I already have the SBO-COMMON database when I'm trying to connect to it. But I just can't connect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not normal for the database to be located on your own computer.  Normally this database is on a central server shared by all the employees, and managed by your IT department.  You need to ask IT what the name of the server is.

Comment: I get it now, it seems that I haven't enabled the other tcp/ip protocol

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old question, but for anyone else trying to connect to a local instance of SQL Server Express the default server name is:

```
COMPUTER\SQLEXPRESS
```

so a back slash not a forward slash. You can use localhost if it is on the local pc or the name of the remote computer as appropriate.

Comment: The reason for this is that the backslash separates the server name from the instance name. If you are connecting to the default instance, you can often omit the `\instancename` part, leaving only the server name.